# Can Karate handle stream of output payload message sent using http2

Tags: http2, karate

My dev team is going to send output as stream of data for a REST microservice. Is karate capable of handling such data ? If not can we integrate with something so that tests can be run in Karate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have a very specific need, write a small Java adapter.

You can use this gRPC project as an example: https://thinkerou.com/karate-grpc/

And note that you can include these calls into performance tests: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#custom

If you are interested in contributing, please refer this thread, someone has created an HTTP2 client: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/474